# Limit of a series of $1$ and $-1.$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

If I know that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n y_i > 0$, where $y_i$ can take the value of $-1$ or $1$, can I assume that the series $\rightarrow \infty$? In other words, if I know the limit is positive, does this remove the possibility that the series contains infinitely many $1$'s and infinitely many $-1$s and hence oscillates?

Comment: Well, if the limit exists, it goes to either $\pm\infty$, so yes.

Comment: I think my discomfort with this is a matter of vocabulary; I'm used to saying that if a limit goes to $\pm\infty$, then the limit does not exist. But I know that if the limit is unbounded, it's different than having no limit, i.e., oscillates between values.

Comment: some people say that diverging to infinity means the limit doesn't exist. That's fine, as long as you are consistent.

Comment: I kind of agree with you.  If I see a phrase $\lim_{n\to  \infty}a_n >0$ I tend to think that means there is a positive real number so that $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n = L$.  But on the other hand if I see $L < \infty$ I take it in the spirit and meaning that it was meant. In any event though if $y_i =\pi$ then it is not possible for $\lim \sum y_i=L$ for any real $L$ (JC Colette's answer). So either the series diverges to plus or minus infinity or.... well, I'm not sure oscillating is the right word but your point is taken.

Comment: If there are infinitely many $1$s and infinitely many $-1$s, it does not follow that the series oscillates. For example, you could have $10$ ones and then a minus one, then $100$ ones and then a minus one, then $1000$ ones and then a minus one, and so on. $\qquad$

Comment: Simpler example of non oscillation with infinitely many of both is simply two $1$s followed by one $-1$ repeated infinitely.  Also I'm not sure if you have a arbitrary number of terms but one never "overpowers" the other but there is no regularly occurring pattern that "oscillating" is the correct word (is it?)... But no matter.  There is no possible real limit. So either it diverges to $\pm$infinity or ... it doesn't but fails to converge.

Comment: @fleablood that makes sense to me. Then, can I say that if $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i > 0$, then either  $\sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i \rightarrow \infty$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$, or it doesn't and there is no convergence. Thus the only possible limit is $+\infty$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the limit is $\ell$ a real number, $\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i=\ell > 0$

then $\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} y_n=\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} y_i\right)=\ell-\ell=0$

If $y_n$ can only take $-1$ or $1$ as value, it is impossible that $\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} y_n=0$. We can see that in the definition of the limit by taking $\varepsilon <\frac12$

Hence if the limit of $\left(\sum_{i=1}^n y_i\right)_n$ exists (in $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$), it can only be $+\infty$ (or $-\infty$).

Comment: ... if it exist. There's also the possibility that it does not exist.

Comment: I agree with the proof but not the conclusion. The limit is undefined but not necessarily $\pm \infty$. Take Grandi's series for example: $1-1+1-1+\ldots$. I wouldn't assign that series the value of $\pm\infty$.

Comment: Yes but the hypothesis is $\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i>0$, so it is supposed that the limit exists in $[-\infty,+\infty]$

Comment: That was basically my question. Under the assumption that the limit is positive, we know it is not an oscillating series that does not tend toward anything (any number, infinity, or otherwise)?